# URL rest api parameter with spaces

Tags: java, spring, rest, jira, jql

I am using the rest API of JIRA to retrieve issues while filtering on the project name and issue type.

When I try to use an API call like:

```
String url3 = "jiraURL/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=GB AND issuetype=Requirement&maxResults=1000";
```

It works!

But when I try:

```
  String url3 = jiraURL/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=GB AND issuetype=Product Risk&maxResults=1000";
```

I got `HttpClientErrorException: 400`.
Meaning my URL is wrong. I think the error lies in the fact that there is a space between the two words that are the issuetype.

I already tried putting + instead of spaces but that doesn't work.
My first call works perfectly. But I don't know how to solve the second call.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters check this question.

Answer (score 3):

Each parameter name and value should be URL encoded. They should then be joined with a separator (either '&' or ';'). Looking at

```
...?jql=project=GB AND issuetype=Product Risk&maxResults=1000
```

I'm not sure whether `jql`, `project` and `issuetype` are separate parameters or if the whole string is a value for `jql`. If the former, the spaces should be replaced with their URL-encoded form ("%20"):

```
...?jql=&project=GB%20AND%20issuetype=Product%20Risk&maxResults=1000
```

If the latter, the "="s should also be URL-encoded:

```
...?jql=project%3DGB%20AND%20issuetype%3DProduct%20Risk&maxResults=1000
```

Comment: the query begins after jql=

Comment: I think you're saying that the `jql` parameter should be (an encoded form of) "project=GB AND issuetype=Product Risk". You would then want the latter.

Comment: That's probably a problem elsewhere. If you paste `jiraURL/rest/api/2/search?jql=project%3DGB%20AND%20issuetype%3DProduct%20Risk&maxResults=1000` into the input on [freeformatter.com](https://www.freeformatter.com/url-parser-query-string-splitter.html), you'll see that `jql` = "project=GB AND issuetype=Product Risk"

Comment: But that is kinda weird. Why is my first api call with spaces working perfectly?

Comment: You should compare both with the freeformatter.com interface.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try?

```
 try {
        String url3 = URLEncoder.encode("jiraURL/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=GB AND issuetype=Product Risk&maxResults=1000", "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```